# Joining two tables and adding column values together

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, in both tables I have a unique column titled phone_number and then a column called spring with 3 others columns. The spring column has a number value. This table has about 3000 rows. I have a duplicate table with the same information but with only about 300 rows. I want to combine the values of both tables' spring columns based on the phone_number unique column.

I have tried doing a MERGE and also a UNION but I don't really understand how they work and kept getting syntax errors.

```
SELECT
    accountstwo.phone_number, accountstwo.deposit_total, accountstwo.summer, accountstwo.total_remain,
    (
        SUM(accountstwo.spring) + SUM(accountstwonu.spring)
    ) spring
FROM accountstwo LEFT JOIN
     accountstwonu
     ON accountstwonu.phone_number = accountstwo.phone_number
GROUP BY phone_number;
```

I can get the tables to join but it creates a new column called spring with only the combined column totals and the original table's other 2700 rows return as NULL. I want to keep the 2700 rows data as well as combine the other 300.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT a2.phone_number, a2.deposit_total, a2.summer, a2.total_remain,
       (COALESCE(a2.spring, 0) + COALESCE(SUM(a2nu.spring), 0)) as spring
FROM accountstwo a2 LEFT JOIN
     accountstwonu a2nu
     ON a2.phone_number = a2nu.phone_number
GROUP BY a2.phone_number, a2.deposit_total, a2.summer, a2.total_remain, a2.spring;
```

Comment: That does exactly what I want, the only problem is that if I navigate away from the screen or try and export out the table as a CSV, then the JOIN goes away. Is there a way to make this permanent? - edit I exported from the query. Thank you!

Comment: @holodout . . . I'm not sure what you mean by "the `JOIN` goes away.  I'm glad the query works for you though.

Answer (score 0):

> in both tables I have a unique column titled phone_number

If `phone_number` is unique in both tables, then `GROUP BY` and `SUM()` make no sense, since the (LEFT) JOIN result can only have one row per phone number. All you need is probably `COALESCE()` for the right table, to convert NULL to zero:

```
SELECT
    accountstwo.phone_number,
    accountstwo.deposit_total,
    accountstwo.summer, accountstwo.total_remain,
    accountstwo.spring + COALESCE(accountstwonu.spring, 0) as spring
FROM accountstwo LEFT JOIN
     accountstwonu
     ON accountstwonu.phone_number = accountstwo.phone_number;
```